# How to store response of rails app to filesystem

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, json, file-io

I would like to generate a bunch of static pages with my rails app, which then will be stored to the filesystem in order to be part of a build step in a [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) webapp.
The filetypes would be JSON and HMTL.

Therefore I would like to know what would be the best solution for this problem. Fetching the site with [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) or something similar, transform it to string and put it into a file. Or maybe write a rake task, which starts curl which then puts it into a file.

Or is there something build-in which can handle this type of problem?

**Update:**
I guess I have to make my goal clearer: I would like to build a website generator, which can export webpages and json to the local file system. In order to get fast response times and to use my existing build process I would like to generate those files and not serve them via rails.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but you might consider something like middleman.  It's meant to generate static files, but you can still do ruby/rails like magic, etc.

http://middlemanapp.com/